# Entering the dummy value in map of bigdecimal type

Tags: java

I have the below map and for a particular scenario i have to enter the dummy value that is of type big decimal and on that i have to diaplay the message

so my map is like

```
private Map<BigDecimal, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<BigDecimal, String>() ;
```

and on one particular condition i have to enter the dummy value so please advise me what will be that dummy value of big decial in ither words can you please advise any sample big decimal value which i can make as a key

```
map.put(** which key **, "Display messaage");
```

Comment: You could use `BigDecimal.ONE` or something as a dummy

Answer (score 1):

Here we are getting an input value from user. When user enter 1 as input then we add a key of type `BigDecimal` and its value of type `String` to map. You can manipulate it according to your logic.

**You can try:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);

        Map<BigDecimal, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<BigDecimal, String>();
        // Input value
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int x = i.nextInt();

        // If x == 1 then add value in LinkedHashMap
        if(x == 1) {
            map.put(BigDecimal.ONE, "Display messaage");
        }

        // Iterate Map to get key and its value
        for (Map.Entry<BigDecimal, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter number: 1
Key = 1, Value = Display messaage
```